# How to setup a Excel Button to execute two specifc VBA Macros?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with the following queries.
I have an Excel file with four sheets - Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C, Sheet D
In Sheet A - contain all Formulas and Calculations.
Sheet D has the Excel VBA Button with the following Macro is created and it is being filling correctly data in Sheet B

```vb
Sub CopySelectedColumnToNxSh()

    "CopySelectedColumnToNxSh Macro"

    Sheets("A").Range("E1:E14").Copy
    Sheets("B").Range("A530").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

I would like to add another function to the button that can executes the following

1. Copy values from Sheet A to Sheet C where there is a table with Header (Months - Jan to Feb) and occupied first Column A. I would like to copy the values under each Month Column from this range B2:M11 without overwriting the previous one

I am trying with the following code but I'm not able to set it to move to new column

```vb
Sub Year_1()
    Sheets("A").Range("E1:E10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("C").Range("B2")
End Sub
```

2. Can a logic be added for the button that for each 12 Clicks (Sheet C copy range is filled) it creates another sheet in the table.

Comment: You don't need a separate function to do that. Just add your code in `CopySelectedColumnToNxSh` and it will work. For second question, can you not check `Sheet C` to decide when to add another sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately just adding the Code from Point (1) to the COpySelectedColumntoNxSh is not working, it adds in the first column in Sheet C but when I click the button again, it overrides it and in addition to that it is not copying the values properly, but it gives me only Zeros.